# Ho to build Connection URL for Google Cloud SQL Postgresql Instance

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to connect my app to a managed postgresql instance on google cloud SQL. The app would be deployed via GKE. Normally, i'd connect via a connection string:

Eg: `postgres://<user>:<password>@<my-postgres-host>:5432"`

But the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-kubernetes-engine) states that:

1. Create a Secret to provide the PostgreSQL username and password to the database.
2. Update your pod configuration file with the following items:

   - Provide the Cloud SQL instance's private IP address as the host address your application will use to access your database.
   - Provide the Secret you previously created to enable the application to log into the database.
3. Bring up your Deployment using the Kubernetes manifest file.

I can do step 1 and 3 but cannot follow step 2. Should the connection URL just be: `postgres://<PRIVATE_ID>:5432` and I add ENV variables `POSTGRES_USER` and `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` through a secret?

Are there any examples I can look up?

**Outcome:** I'd like to derive the connection url for postgresql hosted on google cloud sql.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find example of [postgres_deployment.yaml](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes-engine-samples/blob/master/cloudsql/postgres_deployment.yaml) file, to deploy with kubernetes. Example users proxy, but database configuration section does not change for private IP. For private IP do not use the section [proxy_container]

This is the section stated in the documentation, that you are searching for: database environment variables and secrets section.

```
          # The following environment variables will contain the database host,
          # user and password to connect to the PostgreSQL instance.
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_DB_HOST
              value: 127.0.0.1:5432
            # [START cloudsql_secrets]
            - name: POSTGRES_DB_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: cloudsql-db-credentials
                  key: username
            - name: POSTGRES_DB_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: cloudsql-db-credentials
                  key: password
            # [END cloudsql_secrets]
```

Comment: Thanks for responding @Pawel, this is using the proxy sidecar and I would like to use the Private IP: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-kubernetes-engine

Comment: Database configuration section of the yaml file does not change for private IP.

Comment: It is also important to [create VPC native cluster](https://serverfault.com/questions/938075/issue-connecting-to-cloud-sql-postgres-using-private-ip-from-gke)

Comment: The VPC Native cluster part was where I was getting it wrong, thank you @pawel